Build a GraphRag with PostGreSQL and Apache AGE Extension
I'm trying to understand if it's possible to use PostgreSQL as a GraphRAG. As far as I understand, GraphRAG allows hybrid retrieval that combines vector search and graph search.
It feels like Apache AGE can do graph research and PostgreSQL can store vectors, but is it possible to do hybrid search?
As far as I understand, I'm not sure. You can see the langchain integration below:
https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/graphs/apache_age
It seems that Microsoft is using it for its GraphRAG, but it appears that it's not totally open source as I think that I have to use Azure to use it.
Here is their implementation :
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/blog/adforpostgresql/introducing-the-graphrag-solution-for-azure-database-for-postgresql/4299871
Could you help me to understand or at least tell me if you think that's possible ?
